# ORA-01840 input value not long enough for date format

Tags: oracle

Getting Input is not longer for below Query which is pasted.
Here DATE_WID is Number(10) datatype. As i wanted to between 2 dates, I am trying to conevrt. Can some one  help me here.

```
SELECT     NEXT_SCHEDULE.POSITION_DH_WID,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.ORG_WID,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.DATE_WID,
           CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.DATE_WID,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.SNAPSHOT_DT,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.SNAPSHOT_WEEK,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.CUSTOMER_WID,
           DUE     AS FUTURE_DUE
      FROM WC_RT_CUST_DUE_2TO53WEEKS_VW NEXT_SCHEDULE,WC_RT_CUST_CONTACT_WEEKLY_VW CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS
             WHERE NEXT_SCHEDULE.CUSTOMER_WID=CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_WID AND
             NEXT_SCHEDULE.POSITION_DH_WID=CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.POSITION_DH_WID
             and TO_DATE(NEXT_SCHEDULE.DATE_WID,'YYYY/MM/DD') BETWEEN 
             TO_DATE(CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.DATE_WID, 'YYYY/MM/DD')+7 and TO_DATE(NEXT_SCHEDULE.DATE_WID,'YYYY/MM/DD')
             --AND CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.DATE_WID <>0 and NEXT_SCHEDULE.DATE_WID <>0
             GROUP BY 
             NEXT_SCHEDULE.POSITION_DH_WID,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.ORG_WID,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.DATE_WID,
           CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.DATE_WID,`enter code here`
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.SNAPSHOT_DT,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.SNAPSHOT_WEEK,
           NEXT_SCHEDULE.CUSTOMER_WID, DUE
```

Comment: Change data type of column `DATE_WID` to **DATE** or **TIMESTAMP**!

Comment: I cannot change Datatype here as its coming from view and inbuilt table are used inside view. As i wanted to take data beteween 7 days, i am trying to convert Date and do that.

Answer (score 0):

Date conversion:`TO_DATE(CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.DATE_WID, 'YYYY/MM/DD')` is wrong here. (`/` can not be contained in a column having `NUMBER` datatype)

If your DATE_WID is number and in the format: 'YYYYMMDD' then use `TO_DATE(CONTACTED_CUSTOMERS.DATE_WID, 'YYYYMMDD')` and like that.

[db fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01f590c8e45754f09fd80b5ca2e59395)

But, It is a bad practice of storing a date in different data type.

Cheers!!

Comment: `select TO_DATE('2022/03/23', 'YYYY/MM/DD') from dual` works fine.

Comment: @Adder -- `'2022/03/23'` can not be stored in `NUMBER(10)` data type column (Read the question:  Here `DATE_WID` is `Number(10)` datatype).